# Using react-router get data via ajax and pass to next route

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-router

I have a auth page, when click submit button it will get data via ajax,then transition and pass the data to next route
login.coffee

```
handleCommit: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({ 
        dosomething... 
    })
    .done (data) ->
        this.transitionTo 'dashboard',{data:data}
```

But the transitonTo can't use in async block.so I try to fix it

```
handleCommit: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    this.transitionTo 'dashboard'

willTransitionFrom: (transition, component, callback) ->
    $.ajax({ 
        dosomthing... 
    })
    .done (data) ->
        # transition.redirect('dashboard', null, {data:data})
        callback()
```

The part 1, problem is *this.transitionTo* can't use in async block.
The part 2, something looks fine, via *willTransitionFrom* hook I can get data via ajax and transition to path. But, my aim is pass the data to path too, the *transition.redirect* dosen't work.

How can I get data via async function, correct redirect and pass it?

Thanks any reply

Comment: Own dnd? Uhhh. What about using Dan Abramov's react-dnd? https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd - it really works :)